# bootstrap3 dropdown not showing properly on resizing browser window

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

i was just playing with the navbar of bootstrap and got into this design issue that bootstrap already seems to have. Just go to this example page that the site has: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/. Now resize the window to a smaller width till you get the navbar collapsed and click on the right icon where it shows the navbar elements in vertical fashion. Now click on the 'dowpdown' link so that it shows a dropdown. leave it as it is , dont click it again and resize the browser window to the previous full width. you might see the issue where the dropdown is below the content and is inside a overflow: auto type box. any answers how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding the following to my custom CSS file which is loaded after the bootstrap css. Seems to have worked so far...

```
.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```